# Display none no label chamando por ID não funciona no navegador Safari

Tags: css, label, safari, opera

Creio que algum experiente vai saber me responder!

Não consigo fazer o código abaixo funcionar no navegador Safari e nas versões mais antigas do Opera. Já testei em todos outros e funciona perfeitamente inclusive no IE >= 9!

```
<style>
#teste{display:none;}
</style>

   <label for="teste" >
           chamar input
           <br>
           <br>
           <br>
       <input type="file" id="teste" name="image"/>
  </label>
```

consigo apenas fazer funcionar com o visibility:hidden, só que a proposta é não ocupar o espaço da div e o visibility faz isso.

Agradeço a todos.

Comment: Não entendi... o que quero é clicar em qualquer parte dentro dessa área do label e posteriormente ele chamar o input para selecionar o file

Comment: o input file não é?

Comment: A questão é essa, que nos outros navegadores ele chama o input mesmo com display none

Comment: teria alguma maneira deu chamar esse input clicando em algo só que preciso dele com display:none, teria? ja tentei com jquery também mas não funciona

Comment: Pois ja tentei com position:absolute, e visibility:hidden e buga meu layout!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Em vez de esconder o input, utilize outra propriedade em conjunto com o `visibility: hidden`:

```
position: absolute;
```

Ambas as propriedades possuem suporte em navegadores pré-históricos. Assim o `input` não irá ocupar espaço na div e ficará invisível.

```css
#teste{
   position: absolute;
   visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<label for="teste" >
   chamar input
   <br>
   <input type="file" id="teste" name="image"/>
   outra linha após o input invisível
</label>
```

Comment: Ja tentei com position absolute, mas está bugando meu layout, somente o display none  daria certo! creio que entenderam errado, preciso clicar em alguma div ou texto, e chamar o input file para selecionar o arquivo, só que o input file precisa estar com display none

Comment: O position absolute retira o elemento do flow. Não tem como bugar o layout

Comment: Por isso que estou travado aqui kkkk só não posto meu código pois vai ficar confuso de entender! ja tentei até com jquery e não funfa

Comment: Então tem que rezar rs :D.. ou melhor, tem algo errado no seu CSS... repito: o position absolute retira o elemento do flow e ele não ocupa espaço, fica solto.

Comment: O engraçadinho aí acima votou negativo na minha resposta e excluiu a dele, que estava errada.

Comment: Olha sou um cara que debuga bem meus códigos, nem que eu fique dias mas descubro kk, de momento te informo que consegui tirar o bug mesmo usando o position:absolute que me indicou, falei que bugava o layout anteriormente, mas trocando as posições do input, ou seja, colocando ele mais pra cima ou para baixo de onde estava ja corrigiu!

Comment: @CaioLourençon çuçeçu! Que bom que deu certo. Abs!

Comment: Eu que agradeço já estou a 3 anos desenvolvendo essa bagaça, estou saturado kkkk, Abraço!

Comment: kkk sem problemas, feito, fui!

Answer (score 2):

Vou deixar aqui uma abordagem um pouco mais semântica com foco na acessibilidade. Ela parte da abordagem sugerida pelo Bootstrap. Usando `display:none` não tem como garantir que o elemento vai ficar acessível para leitores de tela

**Resumidamente basta vc criar uma classe, chamei de `sr-only`, e que vc vai usar em todos os elementos que vc quer esconder da tela, mas quer deixar acessível para os leitores de tela**

```
.sr-only {
    position: absolute;
    width: 1px;
    height: 1px;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    clip: rect(0,0,0,0);
    white-space: nowrap;
    border: 0;
}
```

Depois disso vc precisa rotular o elemento para que o leitor de tela identifique do que se trata, para isso vc vai usar os atributos `aria-label` e `aria-labelledby`.

O que essa rotulagem faz é algo como o `ALT` usado nas imagens, mas os `aria` vc pode usar em qualquer elemento. O `aria-label` vai dizer a discrição do `label`, e no `label` vc coloca um `id` que vai ser uma "ancora" do `aria-labelledby` do `input` para dizer que ele é o `input` do `label` com o `aria-label`

```
<label for="teste" aria-label="incluir arquivo" id="arquivo">
    texto antes de chamar input
    <input class="sr-only" type="file" id="teste" name="image" aria-labelledby="arquivo"/><br>
    texto depois do input
</label>
```

Aqui nessa documentação do Google vc pode ler mais sobre `aria-label` e `aria-labelledby` https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/accessibility/semantics-aria/aria-labels-and-relationships?hl=pt-br

E esse é o resultado final, veja que não há espaço entre uma linha e outra.

```css
.sr-only {
    position: absolute;
    width: 1px;
    height: 1px;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    clip: rect(0,0,0,0);
    white-space: nowrap;
    border: 0;
}
```

```html
<label for="teste" aria-label="incluir arquivo" id="arquivo">
    texto antes de chamar input
    <input class="sr-only" type="file" id="teste" name="image" aria-labelledby="arquivo"/><br>
    texto depois do input
</label>
```

Comment: Muito obrigado, já resolvi o problema!